# receiving connection object when connecting from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, nullpointerexception, connection

it's so weird how I can't receive connection object when instantiating it from a servlet, but *I can do it from a standard Java application (with the same code),* 
here is my code followed by the exception

```
    try {
    Statement st = null;
    Connection con = null;
    try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd?user=root&password=pass");
            st = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("SELECT * FROM user WHERE 'userName'="+c(userName));
                st.execute("INSERT INTO user ('userName', 'password', 'email') VALUES ('FEF','RR','GG')");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

java.lang.NullPointerException
at Authentificate.testBD(Authentificate.java:52)
at Authentificate.doGet(Authentificate.java:36)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Your exception handling is up the pole. You must not allow execution to proceed after an exception that makes that impossible. Consider nesting your catch blocks, or indeed using a single catch block for all of it.

Comment: ok, I think I did it now;

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Statement Object is not initilised, that's why you get the exception.

Try before `st.execute(sql);` this:

```
st = con.createStatement();
```

Comment: I missed the line when copying the code, because I was minimizing it, thank you

Comment: @user1951298 Don't forget that if an answer helps you you can mark it as accepted (and upvote it if you have the rep)

Answer (score 0):

you should try st.executeUpate instead of st.execute.